# Should I Use Sans Serif Fonts for Section Headers and Monospace Fonts for URLs

Tags: typography, typewriter, sans-serif

The font I use is Latin Modern.
I want to know if I should use sans serif family for the section headers.
Some people suggest to use sans serif for section headers but to me it looks a bit weird and as if it stands out too much.
I do like the monospace URLs though, I do not want to color URLs because I do not print in color.

Comment: note koma script document classes have an option `egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles `

Comment: Sorry, who's Egreg?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg

Comment: Thanks. This is useful because I use the scrartcl document class. But what is your opinion on this?

Comment: It's not really on topic here. Once you pick a design, asking how to implement it in TeX would be on topic. Personally I don't think I have often used sans serif headings for a serif document, but it all depends: font choice is part of the overall document design and not a simple yes/no choice of "sans serif in headings" that can be made in isolation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What about monospace URLs? I think I like them but are they unprofessional?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Wow! That really works, though I couldn't find this option in the documentation...

Comment: well same answer, I normally use monospace or sans serif, depending on the design (posh name for "random whim at the time")

Comment: I will trust what feels right to me and I will use serif for section headers and typewriter (monospace) for URLs.

Comment: @Amarakon Best option name ever! A few years ago I wrote the author of the komascript bundle that he should provide a document class option to get serif type also for titles and he added that option (without documenting it).

Answer (score 2):

Pairing a sans header typeface with a serif body is a classic combination, even convention in the traditional print world. That said, there is a certain popularity and dominance of serif typefaces in the US for lengthy text in print, including books, newspapers and academic papers, perhaps more so than in most European typography traditions.

KOMA-Script, it has been pointed out, uses sans for headers as the default. Other standard LaTeX classes do not.

Ultimately there is no hard and fast rule when it comes to pairing serifs and sans-serifs: It's all down to external requirements, target audience, medium and, not least, personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It's a "custom" (possibly 90% people would agree with this) to use monospaced font for urls, while you could select any other font. Also, it's very common (possibly 50% people would agree with this) to use bold fonts for chapter and section tiles, while there are many people select other fonts, for example Chinese sans serif fonts in the thesis formats of many Chinese universities. So as you like and you need you could select any other fonts, while it's better to follow the customs or habits of most of people since formats are used to decrease people's difficulty in understanding the contents of the publications which are more important.

For url color, you could set as follows

```
\usepackages[colorlinks,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=black]{hyperref}
```

Comment: Why not `hidelinks` instead of `colorlinks` and then turning them to black?

Comment: @Skillmon Then it's another way.

Comment: No, try `\textcolor{green}{See section~\ref{foo}}` and compare the `hidelinks` approach to yours (admittedly out of scope for OP, as no colour at all will be used).

Comment: @Skillmon It's another problem.

Comment: No, it's not. Your "solution" is no real solution as it colours the links (the colour just happens to be black). If you don't want links coloured the correct approach is `hidelinks`.

Comment: Agreed, but not what is being asked: "I do not want to color URLs"

Comment: @Skillmon But it's convenient to set the desired colors if you want to do so some other day. In my practice it's more useful since I always change between them, and we almost don't encounter the problem you said in practice.

Comment: @Skillmon In my opinion, what the OP really want is deleting the border since it effects the visual appearance and not effecting the printing in black and white while most of other colors will effect. So it's indeed a solution.